# Use of OOcharts api to fetch google analytics data

Tags: api, google-analytics

Hello I am using oocharts plugin to fetch google analytics statistics for my CMS dashboard,
I couldn't understand where I am going wrong?

Here is the default code that I am using of one of the file metric.html to get no of visits

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>With JS</h3>
    Visits : <span id='metric'></span>

    <h3>With HTML Attributes</h3>
    Visits : <span data-oochart='metric' data-oochart-metric='ga:visits' data-oochart-start-date='30d' data-oochart-profile='{{ My Profile Id }}'></span>

    <script src='oocharts.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function(){

            oo.setAPIKey("{{ My Key }}");

            oo.load(function(){

                var metric = new oo.Metric("{{ My profile Id }}", "30d");

                metric.setMetric("ga:visits");

                metric.draw('metric');

                document.getElementById('metric').value=metric;

                alert(metric);
            });
        };

    </script>
</body>
```

I understand the full code, but yet I am not able to manipulate data,i.e., I am not able to echo/print this data. Also when i check my firefox console  to see all the url are properly called, I get an error of 400 bad request, while calling api.oocharts.com

can someone tell me what should be done in this case?

I just want to echo atleast one data like visit: for my site.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You must wait for a while to take effect. May be their server not updated as soon as you add API Key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `{{ profile ID }}` with your Google Analytics profile ID.  This can be found by logging into analytics, clicking Admin, then taking a look at the URL which will look something like this

'https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#management/Settings/a5381475w10244833p10898655/'

The profile ID is the 7+ digit number after `p` in the URL.  In this case, the profile ID is `10898655`.

You also need to replace `{{ api key }}` with your OOCharts API, which you should have generated in the OOCharts admin console using your Google account.